# Google Sign-in in Android with django-rest-auth

Tags: android, django, authentication, oauth, django-rest-auth

I've been trying to add Google Sign-In in Android but have a couple of doubts.
From the Android documentation [Integrate google sign in android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access)
In the server side authentication part `Client Id` is required which is OAuth 2.0 web application `client ID` for your backend server.

From android's documentation:

> Get your backend server's OAuth 2.0 client ID
>   If your app authenticates with a backend server or accesses Google APIs from your backend server, you must get the OAuth 2.0 client ID that was created for your server. To find the OAuth 2.0 client ID

From my understanding the flow would be:

- Android app will get the `auth code` from google which will be passed to the backend.
- The backend will get the `access token` with the `auth code` from the android app and the `client secret`.
- With the `acess token` we get the user's information and the `access token` is saved in the database.

My doubts are:

1. I read somewhere on StackOverflow that we need to create two OAuth client one for Android and one for Web Application. Is this True?
2. Django Rest Auth Login View need to have one `redirect_url` defined but I don't understand what would be the `redirect_uri` in case of Android device or we need to pass this URL while getting the `auth code` from Google.
3. On OAuth Playground I put my backend's `client id` and `client secret` and got the `auth code` and when I passed this `auth code` to my login view I was getting the `redirect_uri_mismatch` but If I put `redirect_url = 'developer.google.com'` It works, I guess the `auth code` contains host information from where it is generated that's why this should be the same as `redirect_url` in my rest-auth view but then for android what it should be?

Here is my Google Login View.

```
class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    client_class = OAuth2Client
    callback_url = 'localhost:8000' # What this should be?
```

Please ask for more information If I forgot to put any.

I am using this
[django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/)

Some helpful link -

- https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/262#issuecomment-256562095  # It says callback URL could be a fake one but I get `redirect_uri_mismatch`

Comment: Hi I am getting both Id token and getserverauth code which is required, can you share code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Finally, I figured it out, Answering my own question so someone might find this helpful.

1. Yes, you need two client id one for your Android device and one for your web application.
2. Just add http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/ as `callback_url` in the GoogleLoginView and put the same in your Google developer console.
3. I don't know exactly if the auth code generated by the Android contains any host information or not but it seems as long as the callback URL you added in the login view class and in google developer console is the same it will work.

Your Google sign in view should look like this.

```
class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = 'http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/'
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

> Note: You only need `callback_url` and `client_class` in case where you are passing the auth code to this view but if in you are passing the `access_token` then `callback_url` and `client_class` is not necessary.

Comment: Hi can you make one YouTube vedio, because I implemented firebase Google sign in Android I don't know how to connect with Django rest framework?

Comment: Did you manage to get this issue resolved. I am still confused as to how it works